# tkinter, using buttons to progress a text adventure game

Tags: if-statement, tkinter, button, order-of-execution

I wanted to make a text-based adventure game. It seemed easy enough, I just make a gigantic tree of if statements and get input from the user at every step. However, then I decided to try and make a GUI using Tkinter. The problem is I am unaware of how to get input from one of the buttons and progress the game.

I have tried implementing a choice variable as ch. The buttons Trigger the method that changes ch. I was hoping I could detect if an input was made and get the ch variable. However, the if statement won't trigger despite being in the main loop.

here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
    #self.root.iconbitmap('')
root.geometry("800x500")
root.title("Diego's Adventure Extravaganza!")

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        #the charecter will be able to make choices
        self.ch =5
        self.index=0
        #this will display the chapter the charecter is on
        self.title = tk.Label(master, text="Text for titile", font=('Arial',18))
        self.title.pack()

        #relivent story details
        self.storyframe = tk.Frame(master)
        self.storyframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.storyframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.image = tk.Label(self.storyframe, image=self.photo, width= 300, height = 150)
        self.image.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.story= tk.Label(self.storyframe, text="this is where the story goes")
        self.story.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.storyframe.pack(fill='x')

        self.buttonframe=tk.Frame(master)
        self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

        #the choices the chatecter can make at the moment
        self.btmZ= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="The zero's button", command= self.clickZ)
        self.btmZ.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.btmO= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the first button", command= self.clickO)
        self.btmO.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.btmT= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the third button", command= self.clickT)
        self.btmT.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.btmTh= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the fourth button",command= self.clickTh)
        self.btmTh.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

        self.buttonframe.pack(fill='x')

    def clickZ(self):
        self.ch=0
    def clickO(self):
        self.ch=1
    def clickT(self):
        self.ch=2
    def clickTh(self):
        self.ch=3

    def cTitle(self,ctext):
        self.title.config(text=ctext)
    def cImage(self,cpath):
        self.photo.config(file=cpath)
    def cStory(self,ctext):
        self.story.config(text=ctext)
    def cBtmText(self,ctext,num):
        if num==0:
            self.btmZ.config(text=ctext)
        elif num == 1:
            self.btmO.config(text=ctext)
        elif num == 2:
            self.btmT.config(text=ctext)
        else:
            self.btmTh.config(text=ctext)

win = GUI(root)

#The main program
#trying to test the buttons, I want a branching story and for the buttons to do many things
if win.ch ==0:
    win.cTitle("Chapter 1")
elif win.ch == 1:
    win.cStory("The story begins")
elif win.ch == 2:
    win.cbtmText("This is the best button", 2)
else:
    win.ch =5
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Putting code above the `root.mainloop()` call does not put it in the main loop. I recommend running the `cTitle`, `cStory`, and `cbtmText` functions directly from the function callbacks (`clickZ`, `clickO`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bad solution: you have to exit the program to step forward.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, title, path, story, btm0, btm1, btm2, btm3):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("800x500")
        self.root.title("Diego's Adventure Extravaganza!")

        self.title = tk.Label(self.root, text=title, font=('Arial', 18))
        self.title.pack()

        self.storyframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.storyframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.storyframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=path)
        self.image = tk.Label(self.storyframe, image=self.photo, width=300, height=150)
        self.image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.story = tk.Label(self.storyframe, text=story)
        self.story.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.storyframe.pack(fill='x')

        self.buttonframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.btmZ = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=btm0, command=lambda: self.click(0))
        self.btmZ.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.btmO = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=btm1, command=lambda: self.click(1))
        self.btmO.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.btmT = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=btm2, command=lambda: self.click(2))
        self.btmT.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.btmTh = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=btm3, command=lambda: self.click(3))
        self.btmTh.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

        self.buttonframe.pack(fill='x')
    
    def click(self, choice):
        self.choice = choice
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        return self.choice

choice = GUI("Testing", 'images/pngtest.png', "this is where the story goes", "First choice", "Second choice",
             "third choice", "last choice").run()

if choice == 0:
    GUI("Wrong choice", 'images/pngtest.png', "this is where the story goes", "First choice", "Second choice",
        "third choice", "last choice").run()
elif choice == 1:
    GUI("Try again", 'images/pngtest.png', "this is where the story goes", "First choice", "Second choice",
        "third choice", "last choice").run()
elif choice == 2:
    GUI("You are bad at this", 'images/pngtest.png', "this is where the story goes", "First choice", "Second choice",
        "third choice", "last choice").run()
elif choice == 3:
    GUI("you got it", 'images/pngtest.png', "this is where the story goes", "First choice", "Second choice",
        "third choice", "last choice").run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on TheTechRobo's comment.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()


class GUI:
def __init__(self,master):

    self.ch =5
    self.index=0

    master.geometry("800x500")
    master.title("Diego's Adventure Extravaganza!")
    self.title = tk.Label(master, text="Text for titile", font=('Arial',18))
    self.title.pack()


    self.storyframe = tk.Frame(master)
    self.storyframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.storyframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    self.photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/pngtest.png')
    self.image = tk.Label(self.storyframe, image=self.photo, width= 300, height = 150)
    self.image.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.story= tk.Label(self.storyframe, text="this is where the story goes")
    self.story.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.storyframe.pack(fill='x')

    self.buttonframe=tk.Frame(master)
    self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    #the choices the chatecter can make at the moment
    self.btmZ= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="The zero's button", command= lambda:self.click(0))
    self.btmZ.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.btmO= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the first button", command= lambda: self.click(1))
    self.btmO.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.btmT= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the third button", command= lambda: self.click(2))
    self.btmT.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.btmTh= tk.Button(self.buttonframe,text="the fourth button",command= lambda: self.click(3))
    self.btmTh.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    self.buttonframe.pack(fill='x')

def click(self, choice):
    if choice == 0:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command =lambda:self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    elif choice == 1:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    elif choice ==2:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    else:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))

def line1(self, choice):
    if choice == 0:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command =lambda:self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    elif choice == 1:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    elif choice ==2:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))
    else:
        self.title.config(text="chapter 1")
        self.photo.config(file='images/pngtest.png')
        self.story.config(text="this is the first line in the story")
        self.btmZ.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(0))
        self.btmO.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(1))
        self.btmT.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(2))
        self.btmTh.config(text="A button", command=lambda: self.line1(3))


win = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the point in having a GUI class if you cant return button inputs?